# Placing code for relative div above code for absolute div, causes the relative div to not show

Tags: css, html, web

I am building a site that has an `absolutely positioned` banner at the top of the page. This div has a container with id `showcase`. Overlaying this banner is the navigation bar and logo, both of these are inside a container div called `navLogoContainer`, it is `relatively` positioned. 
Both of these container divs are NOT children of any other elements (other than body and html), they are independent.

This is the weird part, if I put the `navLogoContainer` code ABOVE the code for the `showcase`, the contents of `navLogoContainer` are not shown, however one of the links is still clickable (the logo), but not visible, everything else (the navbar) is neither clickable or visible.

If I put the `navBarContainer` code BELLOW the `showcase` code, everything works perfectly.

Sure, I could just put the `navBarContainer` code bellow the `showcase` code and everything would be fine, but this results in my code not being as readable, and not following a logical order, which I would like to avoid. Plus, I'd really like to know when the heck it's doing this!

I'm really baffled by this, I've been trying opacities, display properties, z-indexes, everything I could think of, any help with this would be very much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

The relevant HTML and CSS (apologies for the scruffiness of, and the comments all over the CSS, it's not yet at release quality :) :

HTML:

```
<div id="navLogoContainer">
    <div id="logo">
        <a href="/beta/"></a>
        <p class="big">Name</p>
        <p class="small">Description</p>

    </div>

    <nav>

        <a href="/">Home</a>
        <a href="/linkOne">Link One</a>
        <a href="/linkTwo">Link Two</a>

    </nav>

</div>

<div id="showcase">

    <!First showcase>
    <div id="firstShowcase">

        <div id="firstCaseStudyContainer">

            <div id="firstCaseStudy3DContainer">
            <div id="firstCaseStudy">

                <p class="caseStudyTitle">Case Study Title</p>
                <p class="caseStudyDescription">A brief description of relevant stuff<a href="http://google.com">View the site</a> or <a href="/anotherPage/">view a second page</a>.</p>


            </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
/*The code for the navbar*/
#navLogoContainer {

    margin: 0px auto;
    width: 1050px;
    padding-top: 23px;
    height: 62px;
    z-index: 5;
    min-width: 1050px;
}


#logo {

    position: absolute;
    float: left;
    background-color: #00224d;
    height: 62px;
    width: 273px;


}

#logo a {

    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 3;
}


/*The showcase container*/
#showcase {

    position: absolute;
    width: 100% !important;
    height: 399px;
    top: 0px;
    min-width: 1050px;
    z-index: 0;
}

/*The backgrounds for the showcases*/
#firstShowcase {

    background-image: url("first.png");
    margin: 0;
    width: 100% !important;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 0;
}


/*The CONTAINERS for the case studies*/
#firstCaseStudyContainer {

    width: 930px;
    height: 399px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    z-index: 0;
}



/*The 3D containers*/
#firstCaseStudy3DContainer {

    position: absolute;
    height: 177px; /*Case study box height related. DO NOT SET TO AUTO. This value must be done by hand.*/
    width: 410px;
    margin-left: 530px;
    margin-top: 247px; 
    background-image: url("3dtriangle.png");
    background-position-y: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.6s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.6s;
}


/*The actual text boxes for the case studies. They default to auto*/
#firstCaseStudy {

    position: absolute;
    height: auto; 
    width: 392px;
    bottom: 0;
    margin-left: 9px;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    -webkit-transition: all 1.0s;
    -moz-transition: all 1.0s;
    background-color: black;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

Comment: That looks like invalid HTML. Try to fix it until it passes http://validator.w3.org then see if you still have the problem.

Comment: z-index has no effect on statically positioned elements (the default). Your `navLogoContainer` is being covered by the absolute positioned `showcase`

Comment: Shmiddty, thank you so much! I cannot believe I missed that. I changed `navLogoContainer` to position: relative; . Again, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

From what this says the showcase is doing exactly what you are telling it to do.

you put in the navLogoContainer which has no position, so it's going to be anchored to the top. Then you put in the showcase. This has an absolute position with a top: 0 so it's absolutely positioned to the top of either the page or the container element that both of these are in. So it makes sense that it's covering the logo. If you want the showcase below the logo stuff you need to position it below the navLogoContainer.

So if the navLogoContainer is 50px high the top attribute of the showcase should be 50px. If you're looking to have the navLogoContainer just be above the showcase then you need to give it a position:relative + some z-index love so it knows what it's doing.